# View not updating when environment var changes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to use a global environment var as a status to check if the app should show a loading screen (locking the UI and preventing touches)

I'm not using `@EnvironmentObject` because I can have multiple objects for different notifications

Bellow is the code I'm using. Acording to every material I've found online, it should work and the view should update with the correct code. And yet, my app does not change

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
      WindowGroup {
        NewView()
          .environment(\.counter, GlobalCounter(start: 5))
      }
    }
}

struct NewView: View {
  @Environment(\.counter) var counter: GlobalCounter
  
  var body: some View {
    Text("COUNT: \(counter.value)")
    Button("UP") {
      counter.increment()
    }
  }
}

struct GlobalCounterKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static public let defaultValue: GlobalCounter = GlobalCounter(start: 1)
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
  var counter: GlobalCounter {
    get {
      return self[GlobalCounterKey.self]
    }
    set {
      self[GlobalCounterKey.self] = newValue
    }
  }
}

class GlobalCounter: ObservableObject {
  @Published var value: Int = 0
  
  init(start: Int = 0) {
    self.value = start
  }
  
  func increment() {
    value += 1
  }
}
```

I'm using a basic counter for testing purposes, but this should work with enums, strings, etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Environment is not appropriate instrument here - it does not observe observable objects. You need to inject your counter as ObservedObject.

Comment: Ok, then how can I make it observable? I need to pass this var to several children views. And a data manager will update it in an async method. How can I make it update the views?

Comment: @Asperi this is wrong, [according to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environment) : "If the value changes, SwiftUI updates any parts of your view that depend on the value". You can't directly change its values, but you can call mutating methods which, in my case, are not trigerring the views to update

Comment: Yes, documentation is correct, but your GlobalCounter is not a value, it is a reference and it is not changed, changed property referenced somewhere in memory, but it does not relate anyhow to environment value.

Comment: func increment() is not a mutating method. If you change GlobalCounter to struct and add "mutating" to it it is.